# Trying to import a sql file to a remote Database via. c program

Tags: mysql, c

I am trying to achieve this by `execlp().`

The code is :

```
if(execlp("mysql","mysql","-e  \"source /single.sql\" -ppasswd --host 10.240.253.155 Dbname",(char*)0) == -1)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
syntax to use near '"source /query.sql" -ppasswd --host 10.240.253.155 gdas
```

Though when I import the same file via terminal it works fine.

```
mysql -e "source ./query1.sql" -ppasswd -h10.240.253.155 dbname.
```

Usually this `sql` file contains only the `Insert` queries nothing else.

sample from the `sql` file:

```
INSERT INTO
gd_stats(client_IP,virtual_Host,ip_version,pOP,pOP_IP,pOP_Load,pOP_Hit_Stat,request_time,reply_time,time_req)
VALUES('10.240.253.10','service1.in',4,            
'NORTH_AMERICA','10.240.253.15',0,1,'04-20-2015  12:54:32','04-20-2015
12:54:32',7881);
```

I thought their might be a problem with this `sql` file(as it contains only Insert queries) so created a `sql` dump via `mysqldump` then tried to import that dump file but still same error.

The Database is present in the remote host.

I am using mariadb:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB
```

and trying to achieve this on `rhel`.

Comment: I have already tried "--default-character-set=utf8" but still getting the same errror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass each argument to the command separately, right now `exec` Sends the whole string `"-e  \"source /single.sql\" -ppasswd --host 10.240.253.155 Dbname"` as a *single* argument to the command. That is, the whole string will be passed in `argv[1]` to the `mysql` command.

So do instead

```
execlp("mysql", "mysql", "-e", "source /single.sql", "-ppasswd", "--host", "10.240.253.155", "Dbname", NULL)
```

Comment: can u write the command down because I have tried that but was getting database is missing..

Comment: No this doesn't help, after applying this the whole program is crashing...
And the error was thrown by `mysql` not `execlp`.

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh Yes the error was from the `mysql` program because it couldn't parse the argument. The arguments you pass to the `exec` functions is what becomes the `argv` array in the called program. if you have a crash it's because of something else.

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh Also, [read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html)!

Comment: you were right.. it was because of wrong way of passing arguments to execlp and the crash is because the remote Database changed just before I applied your suggestion. Now its all workiing fine.